# Are spaces around SpEl expressions significant in thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-el

I am building a Spring MVC web application using spring boot 1.2.5, using thymeleaf as the template technology.

everything works fine, but i have a weired situation, it seems that thymeleaf spring dialect use the spaces around variable name as part of the variable name.

for example, if i have account object which have name property, when i use the expression ${account} it works fine, but when it has spaces around the variable name ${ account} , it fails, likewise, if i use *{name} it works, but *{ name } it throws org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException exception.

I need to use spaces around my variables for readability, and also because it does not make sense to get an error like this.

What to do to make it work with spaces?